# Django forms redirecting to internal IP on Amazon AWS

Tags: django, redirect, proxy, amazon-ec2, ip

I have two sites that share the same problem, they are both hosted on Amazon EC2. 
The machines are Debian 6.0, with an nginx server in front serving media, and proxying to apache+mod_wsgi to serve django.

Normal navigation on the site works fine, but whenever I click on a link without a trailing slash, or I submit a form, instead of redirecting me to `www.domain.com/path/to/page/` I will be shown `ip-11-111-11-111/path/to/page/`, with `ip-11-111-11-111` being my AWS internal IP address. The forms/links are working as the python code is executed, but when the templates are called, the url is 'built' wrong. Setting `APPEND_SLASH = True` doesn't fix it, and the same behaviour happens with the admin site, so I suspect it is some general issue rather than  a bug in my code.

Has anybody encountered this problem? Any suggestions on how to solve it?

I've been googling this for weeks now and still can't figure it out, any ideas on where I should be looking would be appreciated as well.

Comment: Does this happen when you ssh-tunnel directly on the apache, too? Is the Sites-table setup correct in django?

Comment: could you explain that better? i'm not using the sites framework as I'm only serving a single project on one domain.

Comment: You can use ssh -Lport:localhost:port hostname to map the apaches webserver port to a local port and check on localhost:port if the redirect is bogus there, too.  And Django uses the sites framework by default to calculate absolute url, have you disabled it?

Comment: yes, the sites frameworks has been disabled in my site. I'm not sure I get the tunneling, I'll do some reading and try it out, thanks!

Comment: I can't seem to get the ssh thing working, but in doing some other tests I found out that it believes that www.domain.com and domain.com are two different sites!  

By this I mean that if i go to domain.com/admin I can login, change data (always with the weird redirect problem), etc., but then if in another browser tab I go to www.domain.com/admin it thinks I haven't logged in yet and I have to go through the same process again. The data is being saved, but it's like two different sessions.

Comment: Well, you will have to add more info about the nginx proxying/apache config. If www.domain.com and domain.com refer to the same site, one should redirect to the canonical name, and the other one host the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anybody else has the same problem, the issue was apache redirecting non-www sites to the address it was listening on, which was the internal ip. I fixed it by forcing www. in nginx so that apache will never need to redirect.